# generating a list but only the first index showed

Tags: python-3.x, list

i want to generate a list, in which only odd number get factorial application. However only the first number will be execute, can you help me? Thanks.

```
def factorial(x):
    if x<=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*factorial(x-1)

def odd(x):
   if x%2 ==0:
       return x
   else:
       return factorial(x)


def apply_if(factorial,odd,xs):
    #xs is a list
    i=0
    mlst=[]
    for x in xs:
       if i<len(xs):
          return odd(xs[i])
          i+=1
          mlst=mlst.append(odd(x))
      
    return mlst
```

Comment: In `apply_if` you are using `return` which ends function on first iteration of loop (0 will be always smaller than lenght of not empty list). You need to append elements to list and return them when loop is finished. Also `if i<len(xs)` isn't needed because loop will break after iterating over every element of `xs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `apply_if` function.

```
def apply_if(factorial,odd,xs):
    mlst=[]
    for x in xs:
        mlst.append(odd(x))
      
    return mlst
```

Because at first iteration of loop `i` will always be smaller than lenght of `ws` list (if it's not empty). Also `append` method doesn't return anything so you shouldn't use `a = a.append()` as it just appends element to given list.